# Flask/Bokeh/Tornado6.0.2: Embedded bokeh servers no longer work after Tornado update

Tags: python-3.x, flask, tornado, bokeh, python-asyncio

I have numerous Bokeh Server files in a directory say.. /dir/bokeh/, assume the bokeh servers are called bokeh1.py, bokeh2.py, bokeh3.py
The file structure is like so:

```
|--dir
    |---flask.py
    |---bokeh
          |--bokeh1.py
          |--bokeh2.py
```

I am deploying them all on flask like so:

```
files=[]
for file in os.listdir("/dir/bokeh/"):
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        file="bokeh/"+file
        files.append(file)

argvs = {}
urls = []
for i in files:
    argvs[i] = None
    urls.append(i.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0])
host = 'myhost.com'

apps = build_single_handler_applications(files, argvs)

bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado(apps, extra_websocket_origins=["myhost.com"])
bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)
sockets, port = bind_sockets("myhost.com", 0)
bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)
```

On update to Tornado 6.0.2, and deploying Flask, I get the Runtimerror `There is no current event loop in thread Thread-1`. On deeper research Tornado uses `asyncio` by default and imposes some restrictions. So I add `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())` to the following.

```
def bk_worker():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())####
    server = BaseServer(IOLoop.current(), bokeh_tornado, bokeh_http)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()
    gc.collect()

from threading import Thread

Thread(target=bk_worker).start()
```

However, upon opening the bokeh server url through flask, the bokeh server selected (any of them) do not load and simply return a blank page. How can I circumvent this?

setting `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy))` yields the same result.

edit:The previous code works with python 2/3, Tornado 4.5.3

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a known [Bokeh issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7308). The best way for now is to downgrade to Tornado 4.5.3.

```
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent 4 hours in this issue